# Get the intersect of tables

Tags: php, php-5.4, array-intersect

I have a question. So I have this array :

```
$a_list_id = array(
   0 => 1234
   1 => 739
   3 => 538
);
```

And this array :

```
$a_users = array(
    0 => array(
        id => 15627,
        name => test
    ),
    1 => array(
        id => 1234,
        name => test1
    ),
    2 => array(
        id => 739,
        name => test2
    )
)
```

The result should be :

```
$a_response = array(
    0 => array(
       id => 1234,
       name => test1 
    )
)
```

Because the id `1234` is in both arrays.
I try with array_intersect but not work. Can you help me please ?

Comment: 739 is in both arrays too, but it's not expected in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use loops :

```
$a_response = array();
foreach ($a_users as $array) {
    if (in_array($array['id'], $a_list_id)) {
        $a_response []= $a_users;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

array_intersect will only produce useful results if the values of both arrays can be cast to the same type.  You've got an array of integers and another array of arrays, they can never* match so intersect will always be empty

If you want an intersection between the arrays then you have two options:

- Index the arrays so their keys are the values you want to intersect and use [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)
- Implement your own array comparison logic with [array_uintersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) and a callback function that knows the structure of the arrays being compared

example of the former:

```
$a_list_id = array(
   1234 => 1234
   739 => 739
   538 => 538
);

$a_users = array(
    15627 => array(
        id => 15627,
        name => test
    ),
    1234 => array(
        id => 1234,
        name => test1
    ),
    739 => array(
        id => 739,
        name => test2
    )
)

var_dump (array_intersect_key ($a_users, $a_list_id));
```

Example of the latter:

```
var_dump (array_uintersect ($a_users, $a_list_id, function ($user, $id) {
    return $user ["id"] - $id; // Result should be 0 if they match, as per documentation
}))
```

*They can be considered the same in the case where one value is integer 0 and the other is an empty array, but that's not very useful

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `array_intersect_uassoc`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-uassoc.php

```
function compare_ids($a, $b)
{
    return $a - $b['id'];
}

print_r(array_intersect_uassoc($a_list_id, $a_users, "compare_ids"));
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: @GordonM Sorry, for late implementation example.

Comment: Just FYI, the callback should return 0 if the two values are the same and a non-zero result if they're not.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code using array_search() function:

```
$a_list_id = array(1234, 538,739);

$a_users = array(
 array(
    'id'=> 15627,
    'name' => 'test'
),
 array(
    'id' => 1234,
    'name' => 'test1'
),
 array(
    'id' => 739,
    'name' => 'test2'
)
);

foreach($a_users as $a_user){
  if (in_array($a_user['id'], $a_list_id)) {
     $a_response[array_search($a_user['id'], $a_list_id)] = $a_user;
  }
}

print_r($a_response);
```